# Run `dep ensure` Goland Idea returns `Permission denied`

Tags: goland

I open my project in Goland and in the bottom down corner I see pop-up window

[image]

I click `Run dep ensure` and there is an error in console

> Cannot run program "/usr/local/Cellar/dep/" (in directory "/Users/****/frontend-mobile-api"): error=13, Permission denied

Any ideas how to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a `/` at the end of the location of where `dep` is `/usr/local/Cellar/dep/` should be `/usr/local/Cellar/dep` or should point to the `dep` binary location. Also, make sure that the project is in the GOPATH.